# UrlGatewayLogin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I'm need some help, because I'm a bit confused, I'm trying to login over `url`:

`url(r'^auth/login/', UrlGatewayLogin.as_view(), name='auth-login')`,

and the view is,

```
class UrlGatewayLogin(View):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        page_group = kwargs.get('page_group')
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(token=token)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(request, user)

        return render(request, 'dashboard', {'page_group': page_group})
```

Custom obtain token view:

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

import datetime


class CustomObtainTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        if not created:
            token.created = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
            token.save()
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

MyUser model

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False,)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_token = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_token = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    foursquare_token = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    location_count = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=1200, null=True, blank=True)
```

So I'm passing a toke to my url like so `http://localhost:8000/auth/login/?token=95384449e505a54b60a3842c8db304bd2f3e14b6` but in the end after the request I've got [this error](http://dpaste.com/00QEM1D), so can someone please explain why is this happening, thanks

Comment: Well you `return None` in case `MyUser.DoesNotExist`?

Comment: I've put that as a test

Comment: So probably your token does not fully matches the `token` in your `MyUser` table.

Comment: can you print the `MyUser.objects.values_list('token', flat=True)`?

Comment: I need to log this, in vagrant, I'm creating tokens for them from the DRF specification, so every user have a token

Comment: yeah, but not every token has a user :) Looks like here you use a token that somehow is not attached to a user.

Comment: I see, that is something that I've just realized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171996/discussion-between-petarp-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Django views should always return a HttpResponse, that is the fundamental premise that is broken when you return a `None` in your code.

As Willem pointed out, you need to raise a 401/403/400 when the User corresponding to a token does not exist:

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    page_group = kwargs.get('page_group')
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    try:
        user = MyUser.objects.get(token=token)
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        # raise Http404
        return HttpResponse('Invalid Token', status=401)  # Recommended
```

The standard practice is for the server to raise a 401 if the token is invalid or authentication fails by token. For example, Django Rest Framework by default returns a HttpResponse with the status code as 401 and an appropriate message

```
class AuthenticationFailed(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    default_detail = _('Incorrect authentication credentials.')
    default_code = 'authentication_failed'
```

#### Update

DRF already has a view to obtain auth token: `ObtainAuthToken` and registered as `url(r'^auth-token/$', obtain_auth_token),`

Change your code to access the token from the Token model and remove the `token` field from the `MyUser` model:

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    page_group = kwargs.get('page_group')
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    try:
        token = Token.objects.get(key=token)
        user = token.user
        # If you want to make this behave like a OTP; delete the token here
        token.delete()
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        # raise Http404
        return HttpResponse('Invalid Token', status=401)  # Recommended
```

Definitely don't recommend this method for the use-case - there are better ways of implementing a one-time auth token.

Comment: yes sure, that is correct, in the end there is a problem with how I generate them, it seems they are not attached properly, need to investigate a bit, thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: I'm getting the token generated by DRF specification, after I curl with my user credential I get the token, but somehow that token is not unique for that user

Comment: Are you using DRF's default `TokenAuthentication`? If so, isn't the `token` stored in a separate model? Have you specifed `MyModel` as the custom model? Please add related code for better debugging

Comment: I've added it, but I just realize what you are saying :)

Comment: but still, this should generate token for the given user

Comment: Can you add `MyUser`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171999/discussion-between-petarp-and-rtindru).